# Read the excel data and inserting in below format

Tags: php, mysql, excel, csv

I have data in excel sheet which looks like below.

[image]

I have to read the data(i'll try csv format, please suggest otherwise). Using PHP to read data...

Create two tables, hopefully like below.

1.

[image]

2.

[image]

3. I am expecting ExtJs tree like this.

[image]

I am having trouble in step 1. How shall I read my excel sheet, csv file so that database is updated like table `1`

Comment: so you have a pivot table in excel? And you want the relations put in a sql database with identifiers instead of the values themselves?

Comment: Why 2 tables? One should do. Eatable table,Fields, id,name,type(fruit or vegetable)

Comment: my data in excel is multi level. There could be upto 5 levels of parent, child..

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution, though I did not maintain the same Data_Id's as you did (you seem to increment the id by depth and node, but I just used the row number).

```
<?php
$data = <<<EOT
Eatables,,
,Fruits,
,,Apple
,,Mango
,Vegetables,
,,Tomatoes
,,Potatoes
EOT;

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "test");

$dataInsertStatement = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO Data (Data_Id, Data_Value) VALUES (?, ?)");
$treeInsertStatement = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO Tree (parent_id, child_id) VALUES (?, ?)");

$lines = explode("\n", $data);

$path = array();

foreach ($lines as $rowNum => $line) {
    // convert line of csv to array
    $row = str_getcsv($line);
    // loop through the row's fields and find the one that's not empty
    foreach ($row as $column => $value) {
        if (!empty($value)) {
            // use row number + 1 as $Data_Id
            $Data_Id = $rowNum + 1;

            // track our depth in the tree
            $path[$column] = $Data_Id;

            // insert the data
            $dataInsertStatement->bind_param('is', $Data_Id, $value);
            $dataInsertStatement->execute();

            // check if this node has a parent
            if (isset($path[$column - 1])) {
                // connect this node to its parent in the tree
                $treeInsertStatement->bind_param('ii', $path[$column - 1], $Data_Id);
                $treeInsertStatement->execute();
            }

            continue;
        }
    }
}

$mysqli->close();
```

Answer (score 1):

something like

```
lastvalues=array(); // To hold the last value on each level
data=array();
foreach($lines as $i=>$line){
  elems=explode(',',$line);
  foreach($elems as $n=>$e){
     if($e>''){
        $data[$i]=$e;
        lastvalues[$n]=$i;
        if($n){ // makes no sense for 0th level
           $tree[]=array('parent'=>$lastvalues[$n-1],child=>$i);
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Should give you the data structures. You may use SQL inserts rather than the $data and $tree arrays.